# How to fill in my beard?

Tags: hair

I constantly feel frustration looking in the mirror, I repeatly apply hair growth cream directly to the facial area lacking hair growth for about two months now and can not seem too get that complete bushy beard every male wants to feel good about. what will fix my dilemma?

Comment: Quick suggestion: we know it's a question, this is a questions and answer site. The title should include information about your question(summary or introduction). Try editing your question and you'll get better help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a cream based on minoxidil, you're doing the opposite of what you need.  Minoxidil works, in part, by blocking the reaction of hair follicles to testosterone.  For hair on the head, in men, this reaction may be to stop growing hair, but in your beard, testosterone promotes hair growth -- so minoxidil *prevents* the beard from filling in.

Sadly, it's unlikely that testosterone cream applied to the face would have the effect you want; my experience is that you're pretty well stuck with the beard pattern your genes gave you by the time you're about 25 years old.  If you're younger than that, it's likely your beard will fill in somewhat -- but if older, all you can really do is find a trim style you're happy with that works with the hair growth pattern you have.